# Atmel AVR assembly language multiplying by 2

Tags: avr, atmel, assembly

I'm trying to multiply a 32-bit unsigned number by 2 across registers `r18`, `19`, `20` and `21`, `r18` being the most significant byte. This is my code:

```
ldi r18, 0x03
ldi r19, 0x00
ldi r20, 0x00
ldi r21, 0x00
lsl r18
ror r19
ror r20
ror r21
```

Just used 3 for an easy example so I will know the output. I can't work out whether it's `ror` or `rol` for the rest of the registers. For a 16-bit number you would use `ror` to account for a carry, does this also apply for unsigned 32-bit numbers?

Am I supposed to use `ror` or `rol`?

Comment: The result would be `0x06000000`, so `r19` through `r21` will be unused. `0x03000000` is therefore not really useful to test. Use something like `0x42424242`, of which you'd know the output as well, instead. Also, are you sure `r18` is the MSB? I'm not familiar with AVR Assembly, but it looks like it is the LSB.

Comment: @CamilStaps yeah, i'm not too great with AVR Assembly either, I was told that r18 is the MSB, perhaps it should be at the bottom, And yeah I know those registers are unused, I just wanted an easy number so I wouldn't have to calculate it

Comment: We'll see what the AVR experts say. Btw, multiplying `0x42424242` by two is quite easy too, would be just `0x84848484` ;)

Comment: @CamilStaps Yeah I guess, i get a little confused when reading across the 4 registers, cause it'll only give me a hex representation and i'll have to add 4 of them up is all. (I think, am a bit rubbish at assembly at the moment :s)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Refer to the [AVR Instruction Set](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0856.pdf) document.

For the least significant byte you want a `LSL – Logical Shift Left`. Shift a `0` in as least significant bit and remember the highest bit in the Carry flag.

Then for the subsequent higher bytes, you want a `ROL – Rotate Left trough Carry`. You shift the remembered bit from carry into the right (least significant) bit and the bit that is shifted out at the high side is pushed into carry.

You chose to use R18 as LSB and R21 as MSB, nothing wrong with that.

[image: times2]

Read the above image from top right (LSB is being processed first) to bottom left.

Comment: A picture says more than a thousand words, nice explanation.

Comment: @jippie thanks a million, really helped out cheers! Are you sure about the LSB and MSB i swear MSB goes at the top but maybe I understood that wrongly from my notes

Comment: What do you mean by 'MSB goes at the top'?

Comment: @jippie nvm i just sorted everything out, i thought the mSB got lsl'd but I realize why it doesn't now, thank you!